# CRM 2016 Quick Find View not finding active records

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

We are having a bizarre issue with our 2016 on-premise CRM Quick Find View. Basically, we are not able to use Quick Find View to search for some active records (incidents to be exact).

When we go to the incident's All Active Incidents view and use the search bar (which uses Quick Find View), we are able to search for some active records, yet are unable to search for some others.

We have configured the incident's Quick Find View to search in columns such as ticket number and title. I have compared two such records (one returning and one non-returning) together side-by-side in the SQL Management Studio, and all seems OK.

At first I thought the columns we are searching in might have invalid characters in them for the non-returning record. But that is not the case.

Also, the column names are selected in the Add Find Columns configuration of the Quick Find View. So that's not the cause either.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: you might need to use * in your search phrase .

Comment: Thanks Babak, but it makes no difference.

Comment: I saw that you mentioned you compared the records, but did you also run a query with the parameters and see the results ?

Comment: Babak, I'm not sure what you mean by "with the parameters". I can run an SQL query on that non-returning record and can see it in SQL.

Comment: I mean the filtering the query with columns you mentioned you configured in Quick View settings. So, do you use any language pack ? In the mean time you can develop some plugins on view messages (before/after) retrieving the records and see if it helps

Comment: Ok, I see now. There is no other language pack except English. It's a good suggestion, I will run a test plugin/HTTP request  to try and read that record.

Answer (score 0):

Upon more investigation, we realised that any case and query record created on or after a certain date could not be searched for. Any other record created before that date could be searched for.

We don't know what exactly happened to the CRM SQL database server on that date, however we decided to restart the SQL services on the server and it seems to have resolved the issue. All case and query records are now searchable.

We are still trying to find what caused the issue. I will update this answer as soon as we find the cause so that it might help others.

Thank you all for your suggestions.