# Quick Search do not retrieve "can not find" recently added records

Tags: sql-server, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015, quick-search

I am working on CRM dynamics 2015, recently we became unable to find contacts that are created recently on CRM via "Quick Search", but we manage to find them with "Advanced search".

in the other hand the contacts that existed already existed are still searchable via Quick Find view

The Quick Search view is well configured.
What may be the problem?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You might need to configure columns for quick find. Go to -> Solutions->Expand Contact Entity -> Expand Views-> Open Quick find view->Click on Add find columns. Here you select columns

Comment: Sounds like related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55577345/7920473

Answer (score 0):

This issue is likely a metadata problem with the underlying tables/fields which store the name of the record. A workflow variant of this issue is described by the following article:
http://teameasi.com/blog/crm-quick-search-not-returning-records-that-exist

I have experienced this issue (specifically on the workflow table) and the fix suggested by the author if this article (renaming the workflow) does work for me. I have also experienced similar issues in the past with contact records modified directly via SQL where the fullname field was not set correctly to reflect the underlying name fields.

Obviously this renaming approach is not particularly friendly for fixing a large number of records, I have some ideas for how to fix records in bulk which I will need to prove out. 
Can you provide the following feedback:
- Try re-naming one of the affected contacts to see if this approach also works for the contact case?
- What version of CRM are you on, is it on-premise or online?
- Please test out whether you receive different results within the advanced find if you search based on the fullname field vs the firstname and lastname fields